How to use Pandas to find the smallest value and Nan, then print out the results
csv data
How to use Pandas to find the smallest value and Nan from each group(Fan, LPC, HPC and HPT) , then print out the results
I am very new to python, trying to use pandas to find and print the smallest value from each group. Please help, thank you!

Once you read the file you can use df.describe() or the following commands :
# Minimum value
df.min()
#Null values
df.isna().sum()


Try using group by: split-apply:
df.groupby('Components')['Relative weight, %'].min()

Output:
Components
Fan    28.54
HPC     2.30
HTC     3.52
LPC     6.43
Name: Relative weight, %, dtype: float64


Thank your very much! Would you please let me know how to print out Relative weight, % the header?

IIUC, add .reset_index() on the end.  df.groupby('Components')['Relative weight, %'].min().reset_index()

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!!
